# how to find sum and count of duplicates values in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have dataframe dd1

```
colA    colB    Total   
 A       A        12
 A       A         1
 B       B        45
 B       B         0
 B       B         5
 C       C         1
 D       D         12
```

and i want output like this dd2:

```
colA    colB    count  Total   
 A       A        2      13
 B       B        3      50
 C       C        1       1
 D       D        1      12
```

In count column the value is how many time it occurred and Total column contain sum of Total.

Comment: Do a group by on the first two columns and then count and sum.

Comment: i have tried that but it gives single value instead of dd2 data-frame..

Comment: Suggest posting what you did then see what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dd2 = dd1.groupBy('colA','colA').agg(F.count('colA').alias('count'),F.sum('Total').alias('Total'))
```